# How do you specify missing or NA in datatable's styleEqual()?

Tags: r, datatable, na, dt

I have an R datatable object with empty/blank cells that correspond to NA in a data frame (a correlation matrix).  I want to change the background color of cells if they contain 1, -1, or are blank.

This code creates a table and uses styleEqual() to flag cells with 1 or -1, but I cannot find the appropriate spec for missing/blank/NA.  How do you identify a blank cell in styleEqual()?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, .3, NA),
                 y = c(.3, 1, -1),
                 z = c(NA, -1, 1))
dt <- DT::datatable(df)
dt <- DT::formatStyle(dt, c(1:ncol(df)), backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(-1, 1, NA), c('gray', 'green', 'red')))
dt
```

Resulting datatable:

[image: Resulting datatable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get to the answer more closely at `styleEqual`. It outputs a string from the JS function that has the class "JS_EVAL", which you can view by directly calling styleEqual

```
styleEqual(c(-1, 1, NA), c('gray', 'green', 'red'))

# [1] "value == -1 ? \"gray\" : value == 1 ? \"green\" : value == \"NA\" ? \"red\" : value"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "JS_EVAL"
```

from there you just need to know how javascript handles NA values (NaN), and you can make your own color scheme, and then you can make your own string by just modifying the values

```
myJScolor = "value == -1 ? \"gray\" : value == 1 ? \"green\" : isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ? \"red\" : value"
class(myJScolor) = "JS_EVAL"
myJScolor
dt2 <- DT::formatStyle(dt, c(1:ncol(df)), backgroundColor = myJScolor )
dt2
```

A more general solution is to create a new version of styleEqual, like so:

```
 df <- data.frame(x = c(1, .3, NA),
                  y = c(.3, 1, -1),
                  z = c(NA, -1, 1))

 newstyleEqual <- function (levels, values, default = NULL) 
 {
   n = length(levels)
   if (n != length(values)) 
     stop("length(levels) must be equal to length(values)")
   if (!is.null(default) && (!is.character(default) || length(default) != 
                             1)) 
     stop("default must be null or a string")
   if (n == 0) 
     return("''")
   levels = DT:::jsValues(levels)
   values = DT:::jsValues(values)
   js = ""
   for (i in seq_len(n)) {
     if(levels[i]=="\"NA\""){ # needed because jsValues converts NA to a string
       js = paste0(js, sprintf("isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ? %s : ",
                               values[i]))

     }else{
       js = paste0(js, sprintf("value == %s ? %s : ", levels[i], 
                                   values[i]))
       }

   }
   default = if (is.null(default)) 
     "value"
   else jsValues(default)
   DT::JS(paste0(js, default))
 }

 dt <- DT::datatable(df)

 dt <- DT::formatStyle(dt, c(1:ncol(df)), backgroundColor = newstyleEqual(c(-1, 1, NA), c('gray', 'green', 'red')))
 dt
```

Comment: Amazing & cool.  The question is then what the value of a blank cell actually is.  Apparently, it is not NaN or ''.  I tried to force it to become NaN by dividing by the value:  isNaN(parseFloat(1/value)) but that did not work either.

Comment: It's treated as "not a number" by both JS and R, so using "==" simply won't work - you'll see this if you compare the results of `1==1` and `NA==NA` in R. You have to use `is.na(NA)` in R to get a non-missing logical value that tests for the presence of a missing value. You can create a version of your own "styleEqual" function that does better processing of missing values (using `is.na` rather than `==`) in R if you needed to do this programmatically and not just for a one-off table.

Comment: Should the test expression be in JS or R?  This does not work: myJScolor <- "value == '-1' ? 'gray' : value == '1' ? 'green' : is.na(as.numeric(value)) ? 'red' : ''"

Comment: See edit to my post, which changes the source code of styleEqual to make a new function that handles the NAs in a more general way

Comment: I appreciate you efforts and understand what you are suggesting, but the issue is very specific. The code myJScolor <- "isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ? 'red' : ''" does not work.  Either NA is not being identified or blank cells cannot have a color because when I run the code the blank table cells are not red.  When you run the code are the blank cells formatted with a red background?

Comment: Yes. Works perfectly for me. - edit the second example didn't include the conversion of df to dt.

Comment: Are you entering the code exactly as it displays here (e.g including the slashes?)

Comment: Ah!  My company works from at snap shot of R 3.4.3; when I use R 3.6 your code works.  Sorry for the goose chase.